# InvalidArgumentException in TYPO3 extension we_cookie_consent

Tags: typo3

I am getting an error in we_cookie_consent TYPO3 extension. This error occurs after I installed bw_focuspoint_images extension. I have installed both extensions via composer. My TYPO3 version is 10.4.21.

```
(1/1) #1411840171 InvalidArgumentException
The class "Websedit\WeCookieConsent\Resource\Rendering\YouTubeRenderer" 
you are trying to register is not available

in /www/htdocs/w01c6c77/t3carthago.digitalfairydust.dev/t3carthago2021/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/Rendering/RendererRegistry.php line 60


at TYPO3ICMSICorelResourcelRendering RendererRegistry-›registerRendererClass(WebseditlIWeCookieConsentlIResourcellRendering|YouTubeRenderer')

in /wwwhtdocs/w01c6c77/t3carthago.digitalfairydust.dev/t3carthago2021/public/typo3conflext/we_cookie_consent/ext_localconf.php line 7
```

composer.json code:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Carthago\\CarthagoExt\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/carthago_ext/Classes/"
    }
}
```

The issue is with these two lines in ext_localconf.php of the we_cookie_consent extension

```
$rendererRegistry->registerRendererClass(\Websedit\WeCookieConsent\Resource\Rendering\YouTubeRenderer::class);
$rendererRegistry->registerRendererClass(\Websedit\WeCookieConsent\Resource\Rendering\VimeoRenderer::class);
```

Comment: Did you clear all caches? Tried to remove the bw focuspoint images extension again?

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Ys i have cleared all the caches...I didn't tried to remove bw focuspoint images extension...I need both of these extensions. Any solution?

Comment: I just disabled the bw focuspoint images extension but still the error occurs.